# Handle errors in MobileVLCKit for iOS

Tags: ios, libvlc

I know that I can turn off default `MobileVLCKit`'s error alerts with this option: `--extraintf=`

But how can I then catch errors to handle them? For example, I'd like to retry connection on failure...

I tried `-(void)mediaPlayerStateChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification` but `((VLCMediaPlayer*)aNotification.object).state` never equals `VLCMediaPlayerStateError`.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Are specific errors you are looking for or just the simple "playback failed" thingie?

Comment: @feepk Basically for now "playback failed" will be enough, but it would be great if I could catch more specific errors like HTTP errors, decoder errors, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no public API for those notifications beyond the dialog provider hack we use to notify the user. We are working on a proper API for libvlc at the moment, which in turn will be reflected in VLCKit's forthcoming 3.0 release.

Comment: has the error handling been implemented in the 3.0 release?